# How to refresh state in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, frontend, state, refresh

I am new to front-end and Angular so, feel free to correct me if my questions is not logical.

The issue that I am facing is that I have an application and whenever I change roles (that have different permissions) I can do everything what I could with previous role.

An example, Role A can view dashboard and see all of the users messages. Role B can only see it's own messages. Whenever I change role from A to B, I can see all of the users messages. When I refresh page, then everything works as suppose to.

window.location.reload() will not work here, because this is a single page application and I want to keep it that way.

I know that I should refresh my state, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I've read that in AngularJS there is $state.reload to refresh state. Maybe there is something similar in Angular 8?

Comment: How are you managing state?

Comment: Can you please clarify what's intended as `whenever I change roles` ? Like how does it happens?

Comment: It would be a lot easier for us to help you if you could post code.

Comment: For a scenario like that your best approach is to actually manage the state, which doesn't look like you're doing. Store the user and permission in the state and use effects to refresh the observables when the user changes. A common approach is to use angular ngrx for it. Full documentation and examples can be found at https://ngrx.io/